# ¿Cómo puedo limpiar el shell de python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Utilizo la siguiente instrucción:

```
cl = lambda: os.system("cls")

cl()
```

Me funciona en Visual Studio Code, pero no con el shell del IDLE de python 3.8.5

Comment: `print ("\n" * 100)`  :-)

Answer (score 2):

Respuesta rápida: No es posible limpiar la "consola" de Idle, básicamente por que no es una consola dónde funcionen los comando clásicos. La única forma de hacerlo, y que no es tal, es abrir un archivo nuevo: `File -> New File (Ctrl-N)`

Existe si una versión alternativa de **Idle** conocida com [**IdleX**](http://idlex.sourceforge.net/features.html) que entre sus funcionalidades incluye:

> Clear Shell Window without restarting.

Answer (score 0):

Pues importa el modulo `os` y utiliza esto

```
def borrarPantalla(): #Definimos la función estableciendo el nombre que queramos
if os.name == "posix":
   os.system ("clear")
elif os.name == "ce" or os.name == "nt" or os.name == "dos":
   os.system ("cls")
```

Comment: Esto es justamente lo que está haciendo el autor y no le funciona

Comment: Cuando presentes código python en las respuestas **debes tener cuidado de que la indentación sea correcta**

Answer (score 0):

recién comienzo, descubrí que lo mejor es asignar un atajo de teclado (el que uno quiera), menú Editor, a la instrucción "Restablecer y borrar". Funciona pero es inestable, a veces se cierra la consola.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).